# Changing months from str to int for calculation

Tags: python, string, datetime, integer

I need to change months from a string value to a integer value so I can perform a calculation. I am using the datetime library which can give the current date and I need to compare this to a date entered by the user to find the difference between the months in integer form.

```
import datetime

current_month = datetime.date.today().strftime('%B')
month_join = input('Please enter the month you joined')
month_difference = current_month - month_join
```

I would like the input to be as a month if possible. If not I will just use:

```
month_join = int(input('Please enter the month you joined')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a dictionary which relates the name of a month and its numerical value.

```
import datetime

month_names = ["January",   "February", "March",    "April",
               "May",       "June",     "July",     "August",
               "September", "October",  "November", "December"]

months = {name : (index + 1) for index, name in enumerate(month_names)}

current_month    = datetime.date.today().strftime('%B')
month_joined     = input("Please enter the month you joined: ")
month_difference = abs(months[current_month] - months[month_joined])

print(month_difference)
```

You can also accomplish the creation of the dictionary through use of the `calendar` module's `month_name` list attribute.

```
import datetime, calendar

months = {name : (index + 1) for index, name in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])}

current_month    = datetime.date.today().strftime('%B')
month_joined     = input("Please enter the month you joined: ")
month_difference = abs(months[current_month] - months[month_joined])

print(month_difference)
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, but why not leverage the datetime library to do this for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works perfectly but I will need to compare the year as well as the month. I thought the year would be an integer but when brought in from datetime it is a string meaning I can't compare it an input. Should I add the month within that code? How would I change it to an integer.

Comment: The current year from datetime is:

Comment: datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")

Comment: @Jack, you should just be able to cast it as an integer: `int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))`

Comment: @ErickShepherd , Yes that works. Can't believe I didn't think of that in the first place.

Comment: @Jack Nice! Let me know if you have any more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the strptime method in datetime will be of some use to you. For example:

```
import datetime

current_month = datetime.date.today().strftime('%B')
month_join = datetime.datetime.strptime(input('Please enter the month you joined'), "%B")
month_difference = current_month.month - month_join.month
```

But be careful with this - what if the user joined in the previous calendar year? You would end up with a negative value for month_difference.

You would probably be better off actually getting the full month and year the user joined, turn that into a datetime object, subtract it form datetime.today() to get a timedelta object. Then get the month count from that timedelta object.

You may as well leverage the datetime library as much as possible, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This method allows the user multiple chances to enter a correct answer if they mess up the first time. It also checks to make sure that the number is a valid month. You can also add checks to see if the user needs to include the year. IE: if `current_month - month_join < 0` ask them for the year.

```
import datetime

current_month = datetime.date.today().month
month_join = None
while month_join is None:
    month_join = raw_input('Please enter the month you joined:  ')
    if month_join == 'quit':
        exit(1)
    try:
        month_join = int(month_join)
        if month_join > 12 or month_join < 1 or not isinstance(month_join, int):
            print('Please enter a month value that is from 1 to 12')
            month_join = None
    except Exception as e:
        if isinstance(e, TypeError) or isinstance(e, ValueError):
            print('Please enter the month as an integer. IE. May = 5. If you want to close the program type "quit"')
            month_join = None
        else:
            raise e
month_difference = current_month - month_join
print month_difference
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [monthdelta](https://pythonhosted.org/MonthDelta/) library.

```
import datetime
import monthdelta

current_month = datetime.date.today()
year = current_month.year
month_in = input('Please enter the month you joined')
month_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_in, '%B').date()

# Construct new datetime object with current year
month_join = datetime.date(year=year, month=month_dt.month, day=1)

# Reduce year by one if the month occurs later
if month_join > current_month:
    month_join = datetime.date(year=year - 1, month=month_dt.month, day=1)

month_difference = monthdelta.monthmod(month_join, current_month)
print(month_difference[0].months)
```

Comment: There is no module called 'monthdelta' for me

Comment: `monthdelta` is not part of the core Python library - I just suggested it as something which would work well. If you want to install it, as for any package, you can run `pip install monthdelta` in a terminal window.